# Best place to initialize MobileServicesClient

Tags: c#, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to initialize an instance of the MobileServices client. I wanted to create an instance on a shared singleton object that all pages in my application could use. I tried initializing it on the constructor of my Application in App.xaml.cs but ran into a nasty native exception being thrown. What is the best place to initialize the MobileServices client?

- Constructor of your main page?
- Loaded event of your main page (after doing a null check)?
- Launched event handler of the Application?

Answer (score 6):

The Mobile Services Quickstarts initialize it inline as a public static in App.xaml.cs. For example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/blob/master/client/windows-universal-cs/ZUMOAPPNAME/ZUMOAPPNAME.Shared/App.xaml.tt#L32.

Then you can access it as `App.MobileService` from your app code.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to do this is as a static variable in the App.Xaml.cs, like this:

```
namespace myapp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {

        // This MobileServiceClient has been configured to communicate with the Azure Mobile App.
        // You're all set to start working with your Mobile App!
        public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("https://my-apservice.azurewebsites.net");
```

You can then access the client with `App.MobileService`.